# WPF ComboBoxItem Style gets loaded after Combobox gets focus

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

i am developing an application to learn MVVM. I have an issue now but I could not find a similar case to my.

First my code:

```
<ComboBox Width="100" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
  <ComboBox.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
       <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
     </Style>
  </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

I have a list of simple objects which are structured like below:

- Property: string Name
- Property: bool IsSelected

I bind this list of objects to my `ComboBox` and bind the `IsSelected`-Property of my object to the `IsSelected`-Property of the `ComboBoxItem`. The bindings work fine, my objects are in the `ComboBox`and if I select an item the `IsSelected`-property gets updated.

BUT the issue is that at the start of the application there is no selected item visible. I have to click on the `ComboBox` so the selected item gets visible. I think that the style of the `ComboBoxItem` gets loaded after its parent gets the focus.

Are there any solutions?

Comment: Issue confirmed, the combobox item UI is only constructed when the popup list is actually opened. So before opening, no item based style will have any effect. You probably have to use `SelectedItem` / `SelectedValue` instead.

Comment: Thank you, grek! I have a new readonly property now, which returns the object where IsSelected is true. And I bound the SelectedItem of the Combobox to this new property (Mode=OneTime), now it works. But I think this is a workaround which needs an unnecessary, additional property. So I would be happy if someone can find a solution to solve the main issue.

Comment: I can only offer more workarounds... like in the combobox `Loaded` event, open, update and close: `cb1.IsDropDownOpen = true; cb1.UpdateLayout(); cb1.IsDropDownOpen = false;` But working with selected item/value is less of a workaround and more of a standard approach. The `IsSelected` approach is better suited for multi-selection scenarios than for single-selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set or bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` to an instance of the item to be selected:

```
<ComboBox Width="100" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}">
...
```

---

```
Selected = MyList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsSelected == true);
```

This is how you select an item in the `ComboBox` using MVVM. You don't define a `ComboBoxItem` style.

Comment: This is how I solved it yesterday with @grek40 help. But I did not know the "FirstOrDefault"-Method which is very nice. Thank you for this! :)